# Java JOOQ parse query to ArrayList with object

Tags: java, jooq

I have a problem. I am using JOOQ, with that I created the following query:

```
create.select(
        DSL.field("Mainkey"),
        DSL.field("Market"),
        DSL.field("Coin"),
        DSL.field("Period"),
        DSL.field("DateTimeGMT0"),
        DSL.field("DateTimeLocal"),
        DSL.field("Close"))
        .from(DSL.table("vwCD_All_Selection_" + market + "_" + coin + "_1m_Order_DateTime_DESC"))
        .where(DSL.field("DateTimeLocal").greaterOrEqual(startDateTime.minusMinutes(1))).fetch();
```

Now I also have the following class:

```
public class Candlestick implements Comparable<Candlestick> {

    private long MainKey;
    private LocalDateTime DateTimeGMT0;
    private LocalDateTime DateTimeLocal;
    private String Market;
    private String Coin;
    private String Period;
    public Double Close;

}
```

Now I want the result of the query to be parsed to an `ArrayList<Candlestick>`. I found this page: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-execution/fetching/arrays-maps-and-lists/ that shows how to parse the result to a List, bu that is for a specific column of the select. I want to parse the entire object.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
.fetchInto(Candlestick.class);
```

instead of

```
.fetch();
```

That will give you a collection of Canldestick.

Comment: This works partly. Everything gets parsed to the class, except the LocalDateTime values.
How can I fix that?

Comment: In my database it's of the type `datetime`, but I need the `LocalDateTime`

Comment: What do you get back?

Comment: I get a `null` value, but the value in my database is for example `2021-03-15 12:32:00`

Comment: I will try to reproduce. Why are you not generating the classes from the database?

Comment: What do you mean with `Generate the classes from the database`? I am new with JOOQ, but I can't find anything on their page

Comment: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.14/manual-single-page/#code-generation

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk: I recommend asking a new question with the `java.sql.Timestamp` to `LocalDateTime` conversion problem.

Comment: Okay, I will! @SimonMartinelli still thanks for your help